# TFS 2017 - Process parameters to link to this setting drop-down doesn't work

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm trying to link settings on my builds and the dropdown for Process parameters seems broken. I change the Setting to link to MSBuild and then try to change the parameter that I want to link, but the dropdown under "Process parameters to link to this setting" doesn't drop-down. I click the down arrow next to the default value but nothing drops-down. I've tried changing the Setting to link to several values and under no circumstances does the second dropdown work.

[image]

I'm trying to link the Platform and Configuration so if anyone knows the values I can type them in. I tried Parameters.msbuildPlatform but that doesn't seem to work, so if anyone can get this to work and you could just let me know what to type in there that would be OK for now.

I've tried this in several browsers and on several machines, so it doesn't appear to be a client issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I found a work-around. If you click on the little i in a circle next to Platform and Configuration there's a **Link** hyperlink there that allows me to link the settings, but the problem of not being able to drop-down the list still exists.